# Can I change screenshots when updating my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I am planning to release version 2 of my app. Can I change the screenshots?.There are not much changes in design but some changes in the text, will Apple reject it?

Comment: Are you really sure this is the most relevant place for asking such a question? Please, try also to format a little better your text (punctuation, capitals, etc.).

Comment: If the question solved your problem, it would be highly appreciated if you marked the answer as _solved_

Comment: Still my app in review and already i give  you +1.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked all the time. Just setup your update in *iTunes Connect* with whatever text and/or screenshots you need. You may want to give the users a hint that you just did some "bugfixes". Apple will check your app and you are fine.